# How to Serialize a Control to JSON?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, json, linq

I used to store Control information in an XML file, like so:

```
<Controls>
    <Label Id="heading" Text="This is a heading!" FontStyle="(FontStyleDataHere)" Location="20, 10" />
    <Label Id="bodyText" Text="This is Body text." FontStyle="(FontStyleDataHere)" Location="20, 70" />
</Controls>
```

I have been looking for a printed version of many pages of code that I had last year, and it was the only backup I had left and cannot find it now.

And since I cannot remember how the heck I did this, I always fels that XML was incredibly tedious. So I thought, why not give JSON a go. It seems a bit easier...

Now, given the above code, I was able to create a class of type Person, and Serialize the object and write it to the file (or Console - whatever):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Json;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace SerializeToJson
{
    class Program
    {
        [DataContract]
        internal class Person
        {
            [DataMember]
            internal String Name;

            [DataMember]
            internal Int32 Age;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Person person = new Person()
            {
                Name = "Jason rules.",
                Age = 19
            };

            MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
            DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Person));
            serializer.WriteObject(stream, person);

            stream.Position = 0;

            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
            Console.Write("Json form of Person object: ");
            Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadToEnd());

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

But the problem is, I do not know how to Serialize Controls to Json. And this is what I really need. And, obviously, I will need to then at a later point in time, deserialize them, so they can be re-created at runtime.

Can this be done, with JSON, or would you recommend I still use XML for this?

Comment: Can I ask what do you need this for?

Comment: I have an application that allows its users to rearrange the entire user interface to their liking, so this is why I need to save Control information and state to file and be able to retrieve it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK what I understand here, I am trying to give the answer, You can create equivalent classes for your xml objects.

Equivalent class for Lable object

```
Public class Lable
{
   [DataMember]
    String Id{get;set;};

    [DataMember]
     String Text {get;set;};

    [DataMember]
    string FontStyle{get;set;}

}
```

Equivalent class for Control Obect

```
Public class Controls
{
   [DataMember]
   public List<Lable> Lables{ get;set; }
}
```

Now you just need to Serialize the `Controls` object that contains multiple `Lable`

Now you can serialize object simple using JavaScriptSerializer like this

```
JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
```

**Serialization :**

```
 string jsonString = serializer.Serialize(objControls);
```

**Deserialization :**

```
Controls objControls=serializer.Deserialize<Controls>(jsonString);
```

Comment: Interesting approach. I'm trying this out now. Thank you @Sachin.

Comment: @JasonVoorhees Hey I have updated my code and made it mode clear for you, now you can got it easliy :)