# How do I serialize this object with JSON .NET?

Tags: c#-4.0, json.net

I have the following object that I want to serialize to a JSON string:

```
public class Zone
{
    public string id;
    public string name;
    public Size size;
    public Point offset;
    public List<Label> zoneLabels;
}
```

I was able to use the following just fine before adding:

```
 public List<Label> zoneLabels;
 string json;
 json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(zn);
```

When I add in the:

```
 public List<Label> zoneLabels;
```

and run json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(zn);
I get the following error:

> {"Self referencing loop detected for property 'Owner' with type
>   'System.Windows.Forms.Label'. Path
>   'zoneLabels[0].AccessibilityObject'."}

Basically my Zone object contains some properties as shown and a List of Label Controls. I need to serialize this to a JSON string and recover later to the same Zone object (DeserializeObject to Zone). What do I need to do different?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_ReferenceLoopHandling.htm) when serializing your object.

```
json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(zn, Formatting.Indented,
    new JsonSerializerSettings() {
        ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
    }
);
```

You have other enumeration for `ReferenceLoopHandling` which you can use as per your need.

As OP commented that after using above code, OP is getting Stackoverflow exception which is due to Label nesting indefinitely. So, in this case, you can use [PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/PreserveReferencesHandlingObject.htm)

```
json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(zn, Formatting.Indented, 
new JsonSerializerSettings()
{ 
        PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects
});
```

Comment: I gave your suggestion a try and got the following error: `An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll` - any thoughts?

Comment: I believe, you are getting above error due to Label nesting. I've updated my answer and please let me know if it would works or not.

Comment: I tried your new modified code but now I am back to: `{"Self referencing loop detected for property 'Owner' with type 'WindowsFormsApplication1.Form1'. Path 'zoneLabels[0].Parent.Controls[0].TopLevelControl.AccessibilityObject'."}`

Comment: Do I need to do something like this: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15231657/how-to-serialize-a-control-to-json) or is there and easier way - seems like JSON .NET should handle this almost by just `json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(zn);`

Comment: The issue is with `public List<Label> zoneLabels;` because Label has indefinite nested Label which is causing recursive call. If don't want to serialize `zoneLabels`, you can just decorate that property with `JsonIgnore`.

Comment: Hi @Akash I would like to serialize it. I tried JsonIgnore and in fact it worked for my Zone object but I need the List of Label objects serialized I suspect I will need to manually handle the serialization of Zone? Unless there is a better way?

Comment: Yes, I think you need to handle list of Label serialization manually. I don't recommend to serialize whole bunch of labels, rather you can serialize specific values relevant with those Labels.

Answer (score 0):

After some research and other responses here on SO I found the best way to probably handle this problem is make your own label object for example:

```
public class Zone
{
    public string id;
    public string name;
    public Size size;
    public Point offset;
    public List<ZoneLabels> zoneLabels;
}


public class ZoneLabels
{
    public string text;
    public string name;
    public Point location;
}
```

You can then easily do the following to serialize to a JSON string using JSON.NET

```
List<ZoneLabels> labels_list = new List<ZoneLabels>();
foreach (Label zl in znLabels)
{
    labels_list.Add(new ZoneLabels { name = zl.Name, text = zl.Text, location = zl.Location });
}

Zone zn = new Zone();
zn.name = "Zone";
zn.size = new Size(464, 128);
zn.offset = new Point(x, y);
zn.id = id_new;
zn.zoneLabels = labels_list;

//serialize the object to a JSON string
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(zn);
```

This produces a JSON string that will deserialize back into the Zone object.

In my case I was only setting a few properties of the Label but even if you need to set several Control object properties this would could be one of the clearest ways to handle serializing a list of Form Control objects to a JSON string.